# Move jQuery on *top* of footer

Tags: jquery, hooks, javascript, actions

I am using [this code by Peter Wilson](https://peterwilson.cc/code-samples/load-jquery-in-the-wordpress-footer/) to move `jQuery` to footer:

```
function pwcc_jquery_to_footer( &$wp_scripts ) {
      if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
      }  /* 
      Move jQuery to the HTML footer 
      This should be fine but may cause problems with some plugins as it potentially breaks backward compatibility. Well coded plugins should be good.

      doing_it_wrong_and_loving_it
      */
      $wp_scripts->add_data( 'jquery',         'group', 1 ); 
      $wp_scripts->add_data( 'jquery-core',    'group', 1 ); 
      $wp_scripts->add_data( 'jquery-migrate', 'group', 1 ); 
    }
    add_action( 'wp_default_scripts', 'pwcc_jquery_to_footer' );
```

It works in my Wordpress 4.5.2.

There is, however, one complication. It loads below Akismet's js file.

I need it to be above Akismet's js file, as it better optimizes minification by the plugin W3 Total Cache.

Any way to move it on top of the footer?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a priority parameter to [`add_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/). I don't actually know what priority Akismet has (default is 10), but you could start by trying this:

```
add_action( 'wp_default_scripts', 'pwcc_jquery_to_footer', 9);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but didn't work. I think it's because the 9 is prioritized over 10 for wp_default_scripts not prioritized over wp_enqueue_scripts.

Comment: I was assuming you used the same hook for Akismet. Is there a reason why you would use different hooks?

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. But it moves jquery to the head!

Comment: You mean when you use `wp_enqueue_script` for both? In that case have you used the `in_footer` option?

Comment: Thanks cjbj. 

I can of course deregister and use wp_enqueue_scripts to move jquery to footer but that hard codes the path and would like to avoid. The first code I posted uses something like $wp_scripts->add_data( 'jquery',         'group', 1 ) and 'wp_default_scripts' inside add_action to move jquery to footer. It doesn't actually use something like: 

wp_enqueue_script('jquery', .... )